# How can we stop our immune system from producing a particular antibody?

Tags: immune-system, autoimmune-disease, antibodies

I have always been fascinated with our immune system and, although it is not my specialization, I have been reading about it lately.

Auto immune diseases are particularly interesting because it seems that our body have a given number of systems that protect us from creating auto antibodies, and when these systems fail, we get an auto immune disease.

**My question**

Ignoring any technical limitations we have today (eg. the fact that we are still unable to perform gene editing in-vivo safely), knowing what we know today about the immune system, *theoretically* how could we stop our body from producing a given (auto) antibody?

> Maybe using a vector virus that when injected would kill all effector
> and B cells with those antibodies in their surface? Maybe injecting a
> B cell type that creates an antibody that would attach to the target auto
> antibody and neutralize it? (Just wild ideas, I have no idea if they
> would work even at the theoretical level).

Thanks!

PS. This is not opinion based, this is factual based on the theoretical possible ways to stop an auto imune response based on our current model of the immune system.

Comment: Here's why it's opinion-based: if you ask "how **do** we stop bleeding" people can give you facts of how it is done today. But you ask "how **could** we stop" a thing we can't currently stop. Any speculations and wonderings of theoretically what might work are, of course, opinions on that matter. Not facts.

Comment: No. ""how could we stop **based on our current model**" . But ok, so basically by your logic theory cannot be discussed and we should close entire stack-exchanges like astrophysics and so on where they discuss a lot black holes where we are just theorizing.

Comment: @PedroD. I agree with Ms. Gregory (no relation). Medicine is not astrophysics. They are fundamentally different sciences. Theorizing about black holes is unavoidably necessary since we can't manipulate the research subjects, but we can manipulate the human body. The trouble is, doing so carries a high risk of harming the subjects and a low risk of finding a cure. So there's a different viewpoint in medicine that's reflected in the guidelines of this site. However, I can imagine ways this question could be edited to be fact based. You're welcome to do so.